# Is it a must to have a reply message for synchronous message in sequence diagrams

Tags: uml, diagram, class-diagram, sequence-diagram

I just have 3 doubts regarding sequence diagrams.

1. Is it a must to have reply message for every single synchronous message, where also i want to know whether reply message is a method or just a message?
2. In my below diagram, can I use a synchronous message in a right to left rather than a reply direction (eg: 'showAllCompaniesView' and 'updateCompaniesView()')?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A reply is not needed. If you omit it, the synchronous message will imply the return. You will use a return message in cases where the called object performs certain actions and only then returns to the caller were that comences with further actions. Here's a rough sketch where I omitted almost anything that's not needed:
   [image]

- So in the above picture the first message does not show a return because it's trivial. The `Object2` only performs some action.
- The second message triggers something more complex in `Object2` (that is a message to `Object3`). Still it's trivial enough to omit the return since `Object1` can only commence after the execution of `Object2` for the message has ended.
- The third message has an explicit return. You would probably show that where you had some complex message structure during execution (I only showed one single message but you can imagine a forest here, I guess). Also you will show a return message if you have assignements or any other signature relevant to some return result. From p. 575 of UML 2.5:

> A reply-message-label is used for reply Messages. It has the following form:
>
> `<reply-message-label> ::= [<assignment-target> ‘=’] <message-name> [‘(’ [<output-argument-list>] ‘)’] [‘:’ <value-specification>]`

2. Yes. You can use messages vice versa. If you have a call you will end up in a stack (as you can see also with the additional square on top of the object life line. From a programming perspective that will be more tricky since you have to somehow accept external calls while your program is running. Usually you will need to implement that using threading technology.

---

Some more background to 1. My statement is more out of experience than out of specs. I started reading UML 2.5 again (chapter 17.4.3) to find the details - but could not find a direct statement. Here are the passages I found (in that order below the named chapter):

> - If the messageSort is reply, then the Message represents the return from a synchronous call to the Operation. The arguments of the Message correspond to the out, inout and return ownedParameters of the Operation, in the order of the ownedParameters.

[...]

> A message is shown as a line from the sender MessageEnd to the receiver MessageEnd. The line must be such that every line fragment is either horizontal or downwards when traversed from send event to receive event. The send and receive events may both be on the same lifeline. The form of the line or arrowhead reflects properties of the message:

[...]

> - A reply Message (messageSort equals reply) has a dashed line with either an open or filled arrow head.

[...]

> The message-name appearing in a request-message-label is the name property of the Message. If the Message has a signature, this will be the name of the Operation or Signal referenced by the signature. Otherwise the name is unconstrained.

So far the specs. There are more occurences for *reply* but only to describe what it must look like. Moreover the return arrow commonly used with the dashed line and open arrow is not listed in the table under *17.1 Graphic Nodes Included in Sequence Diagrams* no under *B.6 UML Notations and UML DI Representations*. But it is used in example diagrams like *17.14 CombinedFragment*.

What made me especially frown is the statement *A reply Message (messageSort equals reply) has a dashed line with either an open or filled arrow head.* That looks like you can arbitrarily choose the form (filled or not) with no semantic difference.

Well, the UML specs is made by humans and not free of errors (I already sent some bug reports). However, I'm human as well. Maybe someone else has spotted some details I could not find.

---

As commented by AxelScheithauer the open/closed arrow might be as compatibility with the a-/synch notation. Though, a return from an asynch message seems just pointless. Well, we leave it to speculation unless one of the few OMG authors appears here to tell us the truth xD

Comment: Thnx for you elaboration, it was helpful, can you pls check my third question below the first image, I just edited the question now.

Comment: @YeshanSanthush Please don't start like that. A question may be edited but not extend (or as I've seen altered completely). Please add another one instead!

Comment: The additional question (I rolled back) would anyway be off-topic. SO is not for reviews. Syntactially that drawing looks ok.

Comment: Nice analysis. The obvious things in teal life are sometimes very hard to grasp in the (over?) formal specs. Maybe it’s because the same UML elements need to cover things that are implemented with traditional method calls as well as components exchanging with real messages using datagrams or other communication  mechanisms.

Comment: @qwerty_so The reason why there are two notations for reply messages is simply because nobody could answer the question, why it has an open arrow head in the first place. Since the corresponding synchronous message has a filled head, it seams natural to also have one. For backward compatibility it was not possible to remove the old notation, though. No tool vendors seem to have taken notice. By the way, an example with open head is shown in table 17.2 „Graphic paths included in Sequence Diagrams“.

Comment: I agree with the answer, but would add, that the reply Message if modeled must refer to the same Operation as the call Message: „_UML 2.5.1 The message-name appearing in a reply-message-label is the name property of the Message. If the Message has a signature, this will be the name of the Operation referenced by the signature (which should be the Operation for whose call this is a reply)._“ This Operation could have a method, which is the Behavior (e.g. Activity) that is invoked by calling the operation. The execution of this Behavior is represented by the execution specification.

Comment: @AxelScheithauer I did not want to copy the whole chapter about messages ;-) I'll see to add that one citation as well. I guess that anyone more curious could take the specs and read the _real stuff_.

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "You will use a return message in cases where the called object performs certain actions and only then returns to the caller were that comences with further actions."  Isn't that almost always the case? I would says something like "A reply message is particularly useful when you want to specify the value(s) returned by the method."

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I might elaborate on that. I mean that you send a message and that triggers some more messages on the called side before the called object returns with the return message. And then the caller continues with something else. Often you can even omit the return message here, but I think that in such cases things become more clear with a return message. It's late here (same time zone as you). Hope I don't forget this tomorrow...

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I just added an example to clarify what I meant.